# mysqldump is not working in cron

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cron

First, I created `.my.cnf in /home/username/` with the following text:

`[client]
user = sample_user
password = sample_password
host = localhost`

Then, I executed the command below and it went successfully:

`/usr/bin/mysqldump sample_table > home/username/backup_db/$(date +%F)_full.sql`

But, when I entered it in crontabs, it didn't worked:

`0 0 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump sample_table > /home/username/backup_db/$(date +%F)_full.sql`

I even tried changing the minutes and hour portion but still, it won't work.

Comment: What error message do you see in the system log?

Comment: @ray, how do I see the error in the system log?

Comment: You can start with the `less` command to read `/var/log/syslog`, based on your ubuntu tag.

Comment: To avoid issues with with crontab entries rather replace this line with a simple shell script in which you do you file name substitution and execute the mysqldump command.

0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup_mysql.sh

You are able to debug the shell script and once you are satisfied that it works you can then schedule the shell script from cron. You can also do things like log duration in an email etc..   This will help avoid some of these cron pitfalls

Comment: @ray thanks. However, I was not able to fully view it all since it's very long.

Comment: @Rusty1 indeed you right now. I'll make sure to do it next time. By the way, how do I debug shell script? It is the same as running it manually and see if it produces error in the console?

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri I understand it takes a bit, and while I know there's a good answer already, it'll be necessary for you to learn/do this whenever you have problems. Cron definitely left a message there somewhere. There're commands you can use for searching, such as `/word_to_search` from within the `less` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the percent sign (%), as it has a special meaning in crontab entries, use \% instead.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while but this solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, debugging cron issues always means waiting a bit ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just edit the time like a few minutes ahead to run it in advance hehe