# Can I use a tilde ( ~ ) in a mysqldump cronjob? Linux Cron is not running

Tags: linux, cron

I was having the same issue as [**this person**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343772/mysqldump-is-not-working-in-cron) and [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690386/mysqldump-not-working-from-cron-job), where my command worked locally but inside of a cron task, nothing happened.

Here is what I am trying to run:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -ppassword database_name > ~/Documents/dump.sql
```

This works locally when I type I straight into my terminal! It might throw an error saying:

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure
```

But it still it works. It even works if I put in the user `root` before the command.

Now, here is the CRON (just trying to run it every minute to test if it works)

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -ppassword database_name > ~/Documents/dump.sql
```

And... nothing happens. What I saw from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343772/mysqldump-is-not-working-in-cron) and [this person] was that it was a matter of syntax. I cannot figure out WHY this CRON will not run!

Comment: seems like it puts dump.sql to `/root/Documents/dump.sql` or fails since there is no `Documents` folder

Comment: btw why You dump db every minute? (:

Comment: Consider using `$HOME` instead of tilde as tilde may not work in whatever shell cron is using to execute the script. Better yet, specify the entire path, why leave it up to variable expansion and whatnot?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `$HOME` rather than `~` as tilde expansion is not reliable in a cron job.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/808555/why-is-this-cronjob-not-working) as an example.
[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) is more information about tilde expansion.

Comment: We ended up having to use `crontab -e` and pasting our cron in there. The `/etc/` one was NOT working.